# Converting differences between VS 2010 and 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, type-conversion

Hi I have this code that was written in VS2010:

```
unsigned long CHwFingerprint::toHash(wstring& wmisignature)
{
    if (wmisignature.empty())
        wmisignature = _empty;

    hash<wstring> str_hash;
    unsigned long hash = (unsigned long)str_hash(wmisignature);
    return hash;
}
```

*wstring is just a Unicode string that we created and can be used as CString...

Now I get different results when I use this code in VS 2015.
For example if `wmisignature=HMT351U6CFR8C-PB`
Then the results will be as follow:

- VS 2010: hash= 229184272
- VS 2015: hash= 4005003184

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5):

The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent, so may differ from compilers...

and since C++14:

Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision denial-of-service attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project and select properties.
Under configuration->General->Platform Tool Set, change to v100.